# Old AC and Gas Boiler wiring for new thermostat

Tags: wiring, hvac, thermostat-c-wire

I need help connecting a new 'C' wire for a Honeywell RTH6500WF thermostat.

[image: Current Wiring Diagram]
As you can see the heating is an old boilder with a simple pump to circulate the hot water to the baseboard radiators.

The A/C has 3 connectors to it.
[image: A/C Schematic]

This is the circuit board in the Blower
[image: AC connectors]

This is the current thermostat
[image: current thermostat]

I know I need to run a new wire for the additional wire but WHERE do I terminate the 'C' wire to on the thermostat?  on the C terminal inside the A/C blower?

That wire runs to the compressor outside and then to the Y terminal of my current thermostat.  Do I just need a new transformer? and how would I create the circuit on that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's abandoned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You want the C terminal in the air handler, yes

The terminal you're looking for is indeed the air handler's C terminal -- it's on the fan-delay board (in the back left, from the viewpoint of the picture you've posted).  You'll want to tap the connection it's making to the blue wire using a "piggyback" tab terminal or by cutting and splicing into the blue wire connected to it with a wirenut.